# Why is my computer clock not refreshing?

Tags: windows-10, time, clock

Since about 2 weeks my computers clock does not update on boot anymore for some reason. It does not fall back to a certain date and the CMOS Battery is at 3.288V (checked both with Open Hardware Monitor and in the UEFI) so I don't think that the battery is the issue. It feels like what happens is that when I shutdown my computer that time is saved and simply used when it boots again despite me having activated windows automatic time setting. I can manually refresh the clock by turning that setting off and on again which is rather annoying to do every time.

I have fast startup turned **off**. It was activated when I first investigated this issue and I disabled it because I had issues with it in the past already.

What is causing this behaviour and how can I solve it?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to try a restart instead of a shutdown. If that doesn't get it working, perhaps going to "Control Panel" -> "Clock, Language and Region", then clicking "Set the date and time", go to the "Internet Time" tab, click "Change settings..." and change the server. (Using the "Update now" button usually says there was an error but it works anyway.)

Comment: Instead of what shutdown? I probably should have explained better: If I go to bed in the evening, I shutdown my computer and flick the switch of my powercord (else I have a small LED turned on on the motherboard the whole time). It would not make sense to restart at that point. Regarding the server I also have my doubts. If I switch off the auto-time feature and on again, I get the correct time so the server does not seem to be the problem, or is it?

Comment: Your problem isn’t really clearly defined. The computer should keep the time when the power is turned off. If the time isn’t mostly accurate when you turn the computer back on then there is something wrong with the motherboard. So answering why windows won’t update the time right away for you doesn’t solve the problem. This shouldn’t be happening in the first place. You’re asking like it’s an OS issue but it’s a hardware issue.

Comment: @Appleoddity I did expect it to be a windows problem because I thought that windows would synchronize the clock on startup. I let my computer be down for an hour without power on the power supply and the time was roughly 25 minutes after I turned it off when I just started it. You mention that it is a hardware issue which would fit a few other problems I had recently (keyboard is still being powered, boot doesn't complete). Is there anything I can check more precisely? Chances are also (and not that low) that I tortured my OS enough as I have the same for the third set of hardware now.

Comment: I had this problem once, in troubleshooting I changed the time server.  The problem went away and I never did go back and figure out the root cause.  At one point in history ntp servers had limits to the number of requests you could make a day, I haven’t read any T&C lately to see how that’s changed because a network these days could have many devices that need to get time updates.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Shutting down the computer and starting it is not the same as a restart - the latter is more thorough.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Still: Why would I want to restart my computer if I want to go to sleep?

Comment: As @AndrewMorton pointed out, a restart is not the same. Windows 10 goes in to a hybrid shutdown (fast startup) by default. This means, between a shutdown and startup the OS doesn’t actually restart. It hibernates. Only a restart actually restarts the computer. But, that being said, everything you describe is a hardware issue. Sounds like the RTC has malfunctioned. Are you absolutely sure the CMOS battery is good? Can you remove and replace it anyways, just to make sure?

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned in the original post. I have fast startup turned off (I realized it was not when I first investigated on this issue and I caused issues earlier already, so I turned it off). I will try to see if I can get myself a new battery during the next week and will report back.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Ah, I see I wasn't clear. Restart the computer *once*, then return to the normal shutdown as and when desired.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BIOS date/time reset](https://superuser.com/questions/999469/bios-date-time-reset)

Comment: I am flagging this as duplicated. Despite the old battery being at almost full charge, a new one seemed to have solved the problem. I had many many problems after resetting the BIOS with the change and faced dozens of blue screens and I found that one of my RAM sticks seems to be done as well (or the motherboard slot is faulty so the chances of the hardware playing into that as well are not low. However as I didn't change anything with the hardware but one RAM stick and the battery, the battery seems to have been the issue.

Answer (score -3):

I think the motherboard battery is dead and it does not keep time when you shut it down try replacing motherboard  battery